# Is "similar in A and B" means equal to "similar between A and B"?

Tags: prepositions

For a research paper I have a question about the correctness of the following phrases

The mean activities were similar between group A and group B. The study demonstrated similarity in terms of antimicrobial activity between product A and product B.

Is the word "between" correct here？ or would "in" be more appropriate.

Thank you.

Comment: Realistically there is almost no difference at all.  There is just a subtle difference in that "between groups A and B" sounds like there are ONLY two groups.  But "in groups A and B" sounds like there may be multiple groups, but you only saw similar activity levels in those two groups.  But it wouldn't seem amiss to use either, no matter the circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is a bit subtle.

"The microbial activity level was similar in A and B"  means the same behavior was observed in two distinct cases, perhaps without A and B being aware of each other.

"There was no difference in microbial activity between A and B"  suggests a comparison of the two cases in a sort of competitive manner.

Disclaimer: This is a personal interpretation and I won't claim it's universal.